# Piping text information from the Windows command interpreter (cmd.exe) to a character array

Tags: c++, windows

Is there a way to extract text information from the Windows command interpreter (cmd.exe) to a character array without creating a text file from the command interpreter?

Comment: i.e. run a command like "dir" and retrive the result in a string instead of onto the console or into a file ? That would be the usecase of `_popen`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96ayss4b.aspx

Comment: @mikedu95 You should post that as the answer.

Comment: @JonathanMee wasn't sure about my understanding of the question but now done, thanks :)

Comment: @mikedu95 This looks like the exact answer to me +1

Answer (score 4):

Try `_popen` (`<stdio.h>`), the Microsoft's version of the POSIX `popen` function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(void) {
    FILE * pp;
    char buf[1024];
    string result;

    if ((pp = _popen("dir", "r")) == NULL) {
        return 0;
    }

    while (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), pp)) {
        result += buf;
    }

    _pclose(pp);

    cout << result << endl;

    return 0;
}
```